# Datastax DevCenter freezes on startup

Tags: datastax, cql

Just installed (copied over the app from the downloaded dmg) DevCenter 1.6 on my mac, running macOs Sierra 10.12.6 with jdk 8u152 installed. The application loads a UI (splash screen then a couple of checkboxes in a window for getting started) but the UI is frozen (with the splash screen still there). No response to mouse clicks or keyboard. Also can't click on the app name in the menu bar. The app however is not labeled "Not responding" by activity monitor.

So far I've tried -

1. Looking at the logs both in the app folder and in ~/.devcenter. Nothing fishy there
2. Running the app from a different user account - same issue there
3. Deleting all datastax and devcenter related files (searched by name) on my machine and fresh start - still the same issue

any ideas what I could do here?

I was running DevCenter on a previous mac with the same config / os version but a slightly older JDK, never had issues then.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On OSX, you can specify which version of Java DevCenter uses so that you do not need to downgrade your global Java version.

- Right-click on Devcenter.app
- Click "show package contents"
- Open `Contents/info.plist`
- At the bottom of the file, there's an Eclipse key with lines commented out explaining how to specify the version of Java.  Uncomment the line and specify the version of Java that you want DevCenter to use.
- Save & Re-launch DevCenter

The updated `info.plist` file should look something like this:

```
<key>Eclipse</key>

    <array>
            <string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: As of this writing, you can find the JDK 8u151 download here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html

Answer (score 15):

I reached out to someone at Datastax and learnt that complaints have surfaced about this behavior when using DevCenter with jdk 8u152.

For now, I've downgraded to jdk 8u151 and that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 14):

> **Without downgrade the Java version**

### Scenario

I couldn't create any connection and press buttons and everything was frozen; Changing the `swt` plugin in the DevCenter plugin folder worked. This was my configuration:

- DevCenter version `DevCenter-1.6.0-macosx-x86_64`
- Mac OSX version `10.14.6`
- JDK Version `jdk1.8.0_231.jdk`

## Steps to fix it

1. From [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.eclipse.platform%20AND%20a:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64&core=gav) download the version 3.108.0. (This version works for me)
2. Rename the file downloaded as `swt.jar` (short name)
3. [Optionally] create a backup of the current *swt* plugin jar of the **DevCenter**

```
cp DevCenter/DevCenter.app/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar ~/Desktop
```

4. Replace the plugin with the `swt.jar` downloaded

```sh
mv swt.jar DevCenter/DevCenter.app/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_3.103.2.v20150203-1351.jar
```

5. Startup DevCenter

Finally it worked

[image: Evidence]

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: worked for me too, MacOS Catalina 10.15.3. pd: in my mac the app open normally but gets stuck and no response to click or keyboard, but changing the jar worked like a charm.

Comment: Works very fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

actually, 2 solutions here helped me

1. updated the java version in Contents/info.plist so I did not need to set java_home after this dev center started open but it froze I could not perform anything.
2. Copying the jar version [3.108.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64/3.108.0). to DevCenter/DevCenter.app/plugins/ resolved the freeze problem.